# environment variable 'ROS_ENV_LOADER' is not set

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

When I tried to launch "roslaunch pr2_gripper_sensor_action pr2_gripper_sensor_actions.launch", I got the following error:

```
while processing /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_common/pr2_machine/pr2.machine:
environment variable 'ROS_ENV_LOADER' is not set. 

Machine xml is <machine address="c2" env-loader="$(env ROS_ENV_LOADER)" name="c2"/>
```

I have no idea how to deal with that problem. Could anyone help me out?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50658/environment-variable-%27ros_env_loader%27-is-not-set/) by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting here. Always tag your questions.

You are trying to use a PR2 specific launch file probably on a computer that's not on the PR2. Normally, the machine definitions are controlled using the ROBOT environment variable. Try setting ROBOT to sim:

```
export ROBOT=sim
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on 2012-12-20**:
Hi Lorenz, thank you for you reply. I will notice what you said in the future.  However, after I set ROBOT to sim, the problem is not solved. I still got that error. Can you figure out what's happening there? Thank you.

**Comment by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on 2012-12-20**:
I tried other package such as "pr2_interactive_gripper_pose_action" in the pr2_object_manipulation folder. It works fine. Could it be something wrong in the package "pr2_gripper_sensor_action" itself?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-20**:
My guess is that the package is really PR2 specific and does not work in simulation. That's why it maybe does not use the ROBOT environment variable to select the correct machines to launch the nodes on. I'm not sure about that though.